# Effective gravity at high density - ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

At a high density like `300 dpi` other than the default density `72 dpi` the following `ImageMagick` `convert` command outputs blank pages. It looks strange to me.

```
"convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300  $myfiles -page A4  -gravity center test.pdf"
```

Anyone like to exchange idea?

Answer (score 0):

`gravity` parameter here isn't effective appropriately

> (unable to align the object)

as it can't recognize the position & resolution of `A4` page at `300 dpi`. This is why the questioned command is outputting blank pages at `300 dpi`.

We should avoid using `page` parameter if density is already defined. ImageMagick has a `parameter` called `extent` that can be used to  define the resolution of a page at a given density (here `300 dpi`). Thus we should use `extent` instead of `page` in this case in order to achieve the desired output.

For example,

resolution of A4 size page at 300 dpi is 2480x3508, thus correct command for a set density like `300 dpi` shall be:

```
"convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 $myfiles -gravity center -extent 2480x3508 test.pdf"
```

Here, resolution of `extent` parameter should be proportionately equal to the set `density` for any specific page size.